# adding array elements with for loop JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I want to use for loop for adding elements of the table.

The problem seems to be with `<=` in here : **i<=array.length**. When it's `<` then it works.

```js
var array = [];

for (var i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
  if (i % 3 === 0 || i % 5 === 0) {
    array.push(i);

  }
};

var sum = 0;
for (var i = 1; i <= array.length; i++) {
  sum += array[i];
};

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: `problem seems to be in here : i<=array.length. When its < then it works.`

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Mike Array length starts from 0 to `array.length-1`. Not from 1 to `array.length`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

Answer (score 2):

Array indexes start at 0 and continue through `length-1`. So you want

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
// ----------^----^
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `forEach` function avaialable on array to do it.

```
array.forEach(function(i) { 
   sum += i; 
});
```

By this you need not have to worry about the length or terminating conditions for the loop.

Comment: but you do have to worry about browser compatibility

Comment: It is available in most of the browsers (>IE9, >FF1.5 ...) For more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I know. IE9+ - I still must support IE8

Comment: You can pollyfill to support older browsers. It is available int the above shared link

Comment: I know. No need when the for loop works in all browsers

Comment: Then you can go with the for loop itself. `for (var i = 0; i<array.length; i++)` (As mentioned below). But I would prefer the above solution and even it is correct and works.

Comment: I never said that it didn't work, only wanted to comment on the worry part :)

Comment: I would prefer above solution, if i have to support older browsers i will use either babel transpiler or polyfill (which is the current trend)

Answer (score 0):

This example is working, because i put the console log inside the for loop, look also that i change the name of the second variable from i to j, remember that in js the only block scope is inside functions.

```js
    var myArray = [];


for (let i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
  if (i % 3 === 0 || i % 5 === 0) {
    myArray.push(i);
  }
};



var sum = 0;

for (let j = 1; j <= myArray.length; j++){
  sum += myArray[j];
  console.log(sum)
};
```